# phpunit testing, check the arguments passed to function

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, mockery

I need to test my class, and the class make an Curl request.

I want to check the data passed to the curl request, so this is the code:

```
class SendCurl {

    /** @var GuzzleHttp\Client */
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(\GuzzleHttp\Client $client) {
         $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function send() {
        $this->curl();
    }

    protected function curl() {
        $this->client->get(
            $this->statHatUrl, [
                'headers'         => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
                'body'            => $this->getValidJson(),
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

now as you can see here, I call this class like this:

```
$api = new SendCurl($client);
$api->send();
```

now I want to check the data send to the curl get request
so what I did till now is to use mockery

```
  $client = Mockery::mock('GuzzleHttp\Client');
  $client->shouldReceive('get')
         ->once()
         ->with(Mockery::type('string'), Mockery::type('array'));

  $obj = new SendCurl($client);
  $obj->send();
```

so I successfully check that the first parameter to the "get" method of the client is a string,
and that the second parameter is an array.

BUT how do I compare them to an exact value.

something like:

```
 ->with(Mockery::type('string') && equalsTo('www.WhatEver.com'))
```

dont mind the syntax, only the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the expected values to the `with()` method:

```
$client = Mockery::mock('GuzzleHttp\Client');
$client->shouldReceive('get')
       ->once()
       ->with('www.WhatEver.com', array(1, 2));
```

Comment: can I do some regex on it? like:  /^*wha*$/ or similiar?

Comment: with('/^foo/') OR with(matchesPattern('/^foo/'))

You have all the info at the docs: http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/argument_validation.html